# How to replace/register 'ResizeImageStream' method of class 'Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageEffectsResize' from Sitecore.kernel dll

Tags: azure, media-library, pipelines, processor

I’ve extended `SqlServerDataProvider` to use the azure blob storage account for storing the media library `assests.Everything` works fine but `Sitecore.Resources.Media.ThumbnailProcessor` throws an error in the log file and the content editor becomes slow and unresponsive when clicking on images in the media library.

After doing some further checks found that from where in this method `Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageEffectsResize.ResizeImageStream` error is coming.

I have already replaced `ThumbnailProcessor` processor and patched it via config file but I also need to replace this method `ResizeImageStream`(available in `Sitecore.kernel`) so my custom `ThumbnailProcessor` processor can call the modified `ResizeImageStream` method instead of the default available in `Sitecore.kernel`.

Can anyone please help how to register/hook this method?